# Php -- move_uploaded_file not working

Tags: php, file-upload

Sorry I know there's a lot of posts about that but I can't find a solution in those.

Here's my form :

```
<form id="form1" action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name : </td>
        <td><input type="text" id="name" name="name"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Image :</td>
        <td><input type="file" name="image"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td id='submitAdd' colspan='2'><input type="submit" 
    value= "  Add  " /></td></tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

And here upload.php :

```
<?php
    $ext = strtolower(substr(strrchr($_FILES['image']['name'], '.'),1));
    $ret = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], 'item_images/'.$_POST['name'].'.'.$ext);
    if ($ret) {
        echo 'works';
    }
    else {
        echo 'doesnt work'."</br>";
        echo $_FILES['image']['error'];
    }
?>
```

The directory's permission are ok, no uploading error, but still it won't move the file.
Am I missing something ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to be specifying the absolute save path rather than the relative path it looks like you have now.

Ex. `dirname(__FILE__).'/item_images/'.$_POST['name'].'.'.$ext`

Answer (score 0):

I would move the file under the uploaded file name, and then rename it. Also, some file type checking and security should be added to this.. Sanitize the post ect..  Here is how I would do it.

upload.php

```
<?php 
$fileName = $_FILES["image"]["name"]; // The file name
$fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]; // File in the PHP tmp folder
$fileType = $_FILES["image"]["type"]; // The type of file it is
$fileSize = $_FILES["image"]["size"]; // File size in bytes
$fileErrorMsg = $_FILES["image"]["error"]; // 0 for false... and 1 for true
$kaboom = explode(".", $fileName); // Split file name into an array using the dot
$fileExt = end($kaboom); // Now target the last array element to get the file extension
$fname = $kaboom[0];
$exten = strtolower($fileExt);

//now we do some security checks

if (!$fileTmpLoc) { // if file not chosen
echo "ERROR: Please browse for a file before clicking the upload button.";
exit();
} else if($fileSize > 5242880) { // if file size is larger than 5 Megabytes
echo "ERROR: Your file was larger than xxx Megabytes in size.";
unlink($fileTmpLoc); // Remove the uploaded file from the PHP temp folder
exit();
} else if (!preg_match("/.(gif|jpg|png)$/i", $fileName) ) {
 // This condition is only if you wish to allow uploading of specific file types    
 echo "ERROR: Your image was not .gif, .jpg, or .png.";
 unlink($fileTmpLoc); // Remove the uploaded file from the PHP temp folder
 exit();
} else if ($fileErrorMsg == 1) { // if file upload error key is equal to 1
echo "ERROR: An error occured while processing the file. Try again.";
exit();
}

//give it the new name
$userstring= $_POST['name'];   
$string = $fname.$userstring.'.'.$exten;
$image_name = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $string);

//now we move it. 

$moveResult = move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, "item_images/$image_name");
// Check to make sure the move result is true before continuing
if ($moveResult != true) {
echo "ERROR: File not uploaded. Try again.";
unlink($fileTmpLoc); // Remove the uploaded file from the PHP temp folder
exit();
}
unlink($fileTmpLoc); // Remove the uploaded file from the PHP temp folder   
$imageFile = "item_images/$image_name";  
//$imageFile is the variable to use in the rest of your script.

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just how to fix this problem. This worked for me you can give it a try:
Just change

`item_images/'.$_POST['name'].'.'.$ext);`

to

`'item_images/'basename($_FILES["image"]["name"])`